# Does docker assign docker threads to the contained application?

Tags: java, multithreading, docker, linux-kernel, docker-machine

Docker is in my understanding for the application that it contains an OS.
So when an application spawns threads or forks processes (that could spawn threads) the request the threads that start are some kind of docker threads or request go directly to the host OS?
Does docker manage the application thread requests in any way?

Answer (score 0):

As Docker uses host resources like memory,cpu..etc , all the appplication threads are used form host

> By default, each container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles
>   is unlimited. You can set various constraints to limit a given
>   container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles. Most users will
>   use and configure the default CFS scheduler. In Docker 1.13 and
>   higher, you can also configure the realtime scheduler.

More details are in below link , refer CPU section

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#cpu

Comment: If the container can set thread limits I would assume that it has some bridge thread pool to do that don't you think? Otherwise how? But I am not sure and would like to understand this.